# Check-in/check-out a file to SharePoint2013 via command line or Matlab or other language

Tags: check-out, check-in

Is there a way that I can check out, copy and check in a file to SharePoint2013 via command line or Matlab (preferred) or some other programming language?

I found a third of the answer in this forum.

1. Command line to map the SharePoint folder to a network drive
2. "simply copy".

Copy only works if the file is checked out to the appropriate user (i.e. me).

Therefore, I still need to find a way to check-out a file to me and after copying to check it in.

Comment: search for powershell+sharepoint answers, powershell can interact with sharepoint.

Comment: Hi Danny, 
Thanks for the comment. I started looking into the PS solution. It seems that I need to have SharePoint Server installed on my system for that to work. Please correct me if I am wrong.